# Firebase Web get first Child data from autoChildID

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

My database looks like this:

[image: Database image]

I am trying to get the first child of `unassignedBeaconIDs`, read the data `beaconID`, `major`, `minor` and delete it from `unassignedBeaconIDs`.

Here is my code:

```
var refBeaconID = firebase.database().ref(pathToBeaconIDs).limitToFirst(1);
refBeaconID.once('value', function(snap)
{
    var firstItem = snap.val(); // first item, in format {"<KEY>": "<VALUE>"}
    console.log("The first item");
    console.log(firstItem.beaconID);
    refBeaconID.child(firstItem.key).removeValue;
});
```

The problem is the childAutoID Value. I always get undefined as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So you'll need to loop over the children of the snapshot in your callback:

```
var refBeaconID = firebase.database().ref(pathToBeaconIDs).limitToFirst(1);
refBeaconID.once('value', function(snap)
{
    snap.forEach(function(child) {
        var firstItem = child.val();
        console.log("The first item");
        console.log(firstItem.beaconID);     
    });
});
```

I'm not completely certain what `refBeaconID.child(firstItem.key).removeValue;` translated to, but if you want to delete the child after logging it: `child.ref.remove();`.